Docker removes all the data produced by RUN instruction in the final image
I have custom image which has all dependencies for my tests in cache (gradle). But recently, I have noticed, that my cache is gone in fresh images. I assume CI admins in my firm upgraded docker, maybe...
My Dockerfile:
FROM gradle:7.6-jdk11
COPY . .
RUN gradle test && ls -l .gradle/caches
RUN ls -l .gradle/caches

gradle test produces some caches in .gradle/caches folder. But when I call next RUN instruction - it's gone...
Log:
...
Step 3/4 : RUN gradle test && ls -l .gradle/caches
 ---> Running in b19404b6a13f
...
Starting a Gradle Daemon
...
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  7 gradle gradle   98 Aug 28 08:24 .
drwxr-xrwx 12 gradle gradle  160 Aug 28 08:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x 12 gradle gradle 4096 Aug 28 08:26 7.6.4
drwxr-xr-x  6 gradle gradle  185 Aug 28 08:24 jars-9
drwxr-xr-x  2 gradle gradle   81 Aug 28 08:24 journal-1
drwxr-xr-x  4 gradle gradle   67 Aug 28 08:24 modules-2
-rw-r--r--  1 gradle gradle    4 Aug 28 08:23 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  2 gradle gradle    6 Aug 28 08:24 transforms-3
Removing intermediate container b19404b6a13f
 ---> 01b0d3b3a1a7
Step 4/4 : RUN ls -l .gradle/caches
 ---> Running in e0b1e4fe1b59
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 gradle gradle 17 Aug 28 08:26 .
drwxr-xrwx 5 gradle gradle 55 Aug 28 08:26 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 gradle gradle  4 Aug 28 08:23 tmp
Removing intermediate container e0b1e4fe1b59
 ---> 659e47228e5d
Successfully built 659e47228e5d

So, the final image doesn't have .gradle/caches folder. How can I prevent docker to remove my caches?
Docker version and info:
docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           24.0.6
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.7
 Git commit:        ed223bc
 Built:             Mon Sep  4 12:32:10 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.6
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.7
  Git commit:       1a79695
  Built:            Mon Sep  4 12:32:10 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.24
  GitCommit:        61f9fd88f79f081d64d6fa3bb1a0dc71ec870523
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.9
  GitCommit:        v1.1.9-0-gccaecfc
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
[Pipeline] sh

docker info
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:    24.0.6
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 29
  Running: 20
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 9
 Images: 48
 Server Version: 24.0.6
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: xfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 61f9fd88f79f081d64d6fa3bb1a0dc71ec870523
 runc version: v1.1.9-0-gccaecfc
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: /etc/docker/seccomp.json
 Kernel Version: 4.18.0-477.27.1.el8_8.x86_64
 Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.8 (Ootpa)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 24
 Total Memory: 125.4GiB
 Name: platjenagent10.ci28302344.cloud.alfaintra.net
 ID: 1ca266ec-9d13-4088-ba7f-2000b2d45f15
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: true
  File Descriptors: 173
  Goroutines: 178
  System Time: 2024-08-28T11:23:56.134551161+03:00
  EventsListeners: 0
 Experimental: true


How do I reproduce it? How about RUN touch .gradle/file, does it dissapear?

@KamilCuk yes, it is. RUN mkdir .gradle/caches && echo 123 > .gradle/caches/tmp1 && ls -l .gradle/caches and next RUN ls -l .gradle/caches. Second RUN fails with '.gradle/caches': No such file or directory

I would just set GRADLE_HOME (or how that end is named) to somewhere not in .gradle

The .gradle directory is defined as a volume in your base image: https://github.com/keeganwitt/docker-gradle/blob/59c9fb1b24acf80a7da05dc2461c0f1b2b211527/jdk11%2FDockerfile#L18
...
VOLUME /home/gradle/.gradle

WORKDIR /home/gradle
...

With the classic builder, each step runs in a separate container. The container follows docker's process for a volume without a defined source, it mounts an anonymous volume. And that anonymous volume is discarded at the end of the build step, the contents are never part of the filesystem changes that go in the image.
I believe buildkit handles volumes differently, so you can upgrade and leave it enabled (it should be enabled by default in all supported docker releases for several years now). Or you can store your data outside of the volume. Or you can find (or create) a base image without this volume definition.
